# How can I change background appears between log in and desktop/ ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, themes, desktop-background

I'm not a big fan of purple.

So, I changed my wallpaper of both desktop and log in screen.

(I also changed wallpaper specified in `gdm3.css`.)

When I log in, however, the purple screen keeps pop up while desktop loads (.5 sec).

Is there anyway I can fix it? It is very annoying.